# Python: File being saved as empty when it should be saved with text in it, but only when an unrelated method is run before it

Tags: python

Observe the following Python file:

```
# configmanager.py
"""
ConfigManager controls the modification and validation of config files.
"""

import os

from ruamel import yaml
from voluptuous import Schema


class ConfigManager():
    """
    Controls all interaction with configuration files
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.configvalidator = ConfigValidator()

    # The config directory inside users home directory.
    # Config files will be stored here.
    config_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')+'/.config/MyProject/'

    # The default config file
    config_file = config_dir+'myproject.conf'

    # The default configuration
    default_config = {
        'key1': {},
        'key2': {}
    }

    def _get_config(self):
        """
        Get the config file and return it as python dictionary.

        Will create the config directory and default config file if they
        do not exist.
        """

        # Create config directory if it does not exist
        if not os.path.exists(self.config_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.config_dir)

        # Create default config file if it does not exist
        if not os.path.isfile(self.config_file):
            config_file = open(self.config_file, 'w')
            config_file.write(yaml.dump(self.default_config))

        # Open config file, and load from YAML
        config_file = open(self.config_file, 'r')
        config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)

        # Validate config
        self.configvalidator.validate(config)

        return config

    def _save_config(self, config):
        """
        Save the config file to disk as YAML
        """

        # Open current config file
        config_file = open(self.config_file, 'w')

        # Validate new config
        # THE ERROR IS HERE
        # If this runs then the config file gets saved as an empty file.
        self.configvalidator.validate(config)

        # This shows that the 'config' variable still holds the data
        print(config)

        # This shows that yaml.dump() is working correctly
        print(yaml.dump(config))

        config_file.write(yaml.dump(config))

    def edit_config(self):
        """
        Edits the configuration file
        """

        config = self._get_config()

        # Perform manipulation on config here
        # No actual changes to the config are necessary for the bug to occur

        self._save_config(config)


class ConfigValidator():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Config file schema
        # Used for validating the config file with voluptuous
        self.schema = Schema({
            'key1': {},
            'key2': {},
        })

    def validate(self, config):
        """
        Validates the data against the defined schema.
        """
        self.schema(config)

app = ConfigManager()
app.edit_config()
```

-

```
# ~/.config/MyProject/myproject.conf
key1: {}
key2: {}
```

## Description of my module

This is a module I am working on which is for modifying the config file for my project. It accesses the file in `~/.config/MyProject/myproject.conf`, which is saved in YAML format, and stores various pieces of information that are used by my program. I have removed as much of the code as I can, leaving only that necessary for understanding the bug.

### ConfigManager

`ConfigManager` is the class containing methods for manipulating my config file. Here it contains three methods: `_get_config()`, `_save_config()`, and `edit_config()`. When instantised, it will get an instance of `ConfigValidator` (described below), and assign it to `self.configvalidator`.

#### _get_config

`_get_config()` simply opens the file defined by the class variables, specifically `~/.config/MyProject/myproject.conf`, or creates the file with default values if it does not exist. The file is saved in YAML format, so this method loads it into a python object, using [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/), validates it using `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` and returns it for use by other pieces of code.

#### _save_config

`_save_config()` is where the error occurs, which is described in detail below. It's purpose is to validate the given data, and if it is valid, save it to disk in YAML format.

#### edit_config

This a generic function, which, in my program, would make specific changes to my config file, depending on the arguments given. In my example, this function simply gets the config file with `self._get_config()`, and then saves it using `self._save_config`, without making any changes.

### ConfigValidator

This class is for validating my config file using [`voluptuous`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous). When instantised, it will create the schema that is to be used, and assign it to `self.schema`. When the `validate` method is run, it validates the given data using `voluptuous`.

## The error

Observe the line `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` in `ConfigManager._save_config()`. This will validate the given data against the schema, and raise an error if it does not pass validation.

But, in the following line `config_file.write(yaml.dump(config))`, which simply saves the given data to a file as YAML, it will instead save an **empty** file to disk. (Note: the file is empty, not deleted)

If I **disable** the validation, by commenting out `self.configvalidator.validate(config)`, then the file **is written correctly** as YAML.

*If `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` is run, then the config file is saved as an empty file.*

## My testing

As can be seen with the line `print(config)`, the data in the variable `config` **does not change** after being used for validation, yet when being saved to disk, it would seem that `config` is an empty variable.

`print(yaml.dump(config))` shows that `ruamel.yaml` does work correctly.

If I change `edit_config` to give invalid data to `_save_config`, then `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` will raise an error, as expected. `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` is running correctly.

## End

If `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` is run, then `config_file.write(yaml.dump(config))` saves the config file as an empty file, despite the data in the variable `config` not changing.

If `self.configvalidator.validate(config)` is **not** run, then `config_file.write(yaml.dump(config))` saves the file correctly.

That is my error, and it makes absolutely no sense to me.

If your keen to help, then `configmanager.py` should run correctly (with the error) on your machine, as long as it has access to `ruamel.yaml` and `voluptuous`. It will create `~/.config/MyProject/myproject.conf`, then save it as empty. Save my example `myproject.conf` to see how it is then saved as empty when `configmanager.py` is run. If `configmanager.py` is run again, when `myproject.conf` is empty, then a validation error will be raised in `_get_config`, as expected.

I am so confused by this bug, so if you have any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Not going to bother going through this in detail, but you've got at least one, and probably more than one cases where you `open` a file for write, write to it, don't close it (or even let it go out of scope) and open it again for `read`, which means you may be reading incomplete (unflushed) file data. Use the `with` statement, always, particularly when the file is opened for `write`, so at the end of the `with` block, you're in a known, predictable state (any data written is definitely visible on disk).

Comment: Implementing `with` does solve the isssue, thanks. No clue why it works, but whatever ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Just adding to @ShadowRanger explanation: File Input/Output operations are computationally expensive. This means that it takes a relatively long time to access and write to files on the disk compared to other operations. When opening and writing to a file python buffers your output and writes to the file when a larger chunk of data has accumulated in order to save on those costly operations. When you call close on the file object, the buffer is emptied, no matter how much data it has stored. Reopening a file before the content has been (completely) written may therefore cause problems.